# bash script that handles prompts

Tags: bash, shell, suse

I was wondering how I would handle prompts that happen after a command is called within a script.

I.e. I would like to call the command

```
sudo ./asadmin change-admin-password
```

But that asks me to specify a username and press enter, then the old password and press enter and then the new password twice.

Can I handle this within the bash script?

Comment: It depends on whether `change-admin-password` is reading from standard input or directly from a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If the script is reading from standard input, you can simply pipe the necessary data to the script.

```
printf '%s\n' "username" "password" "password" | sudo change-admin-password
```

However, this will fail if the script is trying to read an item directly from the terminal (which seems likely, at least in the case of the passwords).

Comment: Is there any way to impersonate the terminal?